# Double-clicking my Apple earbud remote brings up Siri

Tags: itunes, headphones, siri, macos

With macOS Sierra pushing Siri as a very cool new feature, the behaviour of my (wired) Apple earbuds has changed.  When I give it a single tap, the music will pause or play, which is normal.  However, I'm also used to double-tapping to advance to the next song, like on my iPhone.  That feature is gone.  Also, on the first tap, the "Enable Siri?" dialog comes up: I decided to disable Siri as I don't use it much and the additional battery drain (that I may be making up) doesn't seem worthwhile to me.

How can I disable this dialog and revert my iTunes behaviour back to what I'm used to?

[image]